# Connect method long time laravel

Tags: http, laravel-8

I'm tracking that it takes a long loading time to enter the site.

What I've tried.

1. Create a simple text file, set it up on the route, and test it
   (It took time to load even simple text messages )
2. Fiddler test, pictures are listed below.
3. Change code logic

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the domain connection.

The site where I purchased the domain was connecting the name servers to aws r3
in AWS R3
The IP address associated with the site I will use is
There should be only one EC2, but I checked that unknown IPs were included.
I set up only the EC2 Public IP and tested it, and the normal speed came out.